# Do anything you want or do anything you want to do

Tags: auxiliary-verbs

Recently, I came across a piece of news. It was about girls being sold off for marriage by their parents after reaching  a certain age and how they were not allowed to live as they pleased.
After watching it, I felt so bad for the girls. 
So I decided to never to do it to my would be wife (or wife  to-be? What ever you call it). 
So in a hypothetical situation ( as I have not planned to get married yet)
if my would be wife asked me if I would treat her the same way and in an attempt to letting her know that I won't,  what my answer should be?

A. You are free to do anything you want to do. Or

B. You are free to do anything you want.

Is **To Do** necessary in the first sentence? And

Do both have different meaning from each other?

Answer (score 2):

> You are free to do anything you want to do

In this, the 'to do' part is redundant and you don't need to repeat it.

> You are free to do anything you want

is what generally practiced. Many Google books have the same example; one is [here](https://books.google.co.in/books?id=XHqi2Bb4-pMC&pg=PA110&lpg=PA110&dq=%22free%20to%20do%20anything%20you%20want%22&source=bl&ots=EMEl3HSZHy&sig=ACfU3U3nKfyZ3YGO6GbqLBc6BXWSFuJD3w&hl=en&sa=X&ved=2ahUKEwjOtZ2mxKvgAhVMQ48KHfFqA184ChDoATACegQIBBAB#v=onepage&q=%22free%20to%20do%20anything%20you%20want%22&f=false).

Comment: And just to make clear the answer to part of the question - yes, they would be read as entirely equivalent. However, if you want to include the "to do" for stylistic or poetic/metrical reasons, it is perfectly acceptable. In casual speech, it would seem stilted.